# I'm using auditd, how to exclude auditd collect log about cron (ubuntu20.04)

Tags: ubuntu, linux-audit

I'm using auditd. I don't want to collect log about cron in auditd but it collect cron.
If I don't want to collect aunditd log, how to make rule in audit.rules

I wrote auditctl -a never,exit -F exe=/usr/sbin/cron

but it cannot work

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following auditd rules to the `/etc/audit/rules.d/audit.rules` file:

```
-a never,user -F subj_type=crond_t
-a exit,never -F subj_type=crond_t
```

After that, run

```
augenrules --load
```

And restart auditd

```
service auditd restart
```

**Note that this will NOT work if SELinux is disabled**

Comment: what if I don't use SELinux, how to do it? Is there no ways?

Comment: for testing,you could always set selinux to permissive and see if the changes take effect